Paragraph inside a flexbox is not getting centered
I have made a card container which contains an image and a paragraph.
I gave the card container display flex and align-items and justify-content both centre. The image got centered as expected but the paragraph is not getting centred.
I have a utility CSS where I have given the display: flex and flex- direction: column properties.
Here is the code.


.spotifyplaylists {
  padding: 20px 29px;
  h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}

.card {
  width: 186.73px;
  height: 237.14px;
  padding-top: 36px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 12px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  img {
    width: 152px;
    aspect-ratio: 1 1;
    border-radius: 8px;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: var(--grey);
    line-height: 16px;
  }
}
<div class="spotifyplaylists">
  <h1>Spotify Playlists</h1>
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./asset 19.jpeg" alt="image">
      <p>With Sachin-Jigar, Amit Trivedi, Mithoon</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--cardcont ends-->
</div>
<!--spotiplay ends-->




Add the whole code to a stackblitz or plunker and post it. The style can be affected by parent components

@StefaniToto One is required to post a [mcve] here, within the question, and not a link to any other site.

i dont want to change the text-align of the paragraph , the justify content and align item both are centered, but its affect is only getting applied to img but not the paragraph. i want to know what is the reason behind that. I have also tried to increase the width of the card, still no use

The card section is already centered and the image and paragraph are both set in the center but your card width is small to the paragraph content so you see the paragraph is not centered If you see, just increase the card width so you can show the paragraph center
Also, you don't change the card width and need to center the paragraph text; just add text-align:center to the paragraph tag so the text is set to the center. Below is the code for your requirements.


.spotifyplaylists {
    padding: 20px 29px;
}

.spotifyplaylists h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
}

.card {
    width: 186.73px;
    height: 237.14px;
    padding-top: 36px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 12px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.card img {
    width: 152px;
    aspect-ratio: 1 1;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.card p {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #808080;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}
<div class="spotifyplaylists">
    <h1>Spotify Playlists</h1>
    <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="image">
            <p>With Sachin-Jigar, Amit Trivedi, Mithoon</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




i dont want to change the text-align of the paragraph , the justify content and align item both are centered, but its affect is only getting applied to img but not the paragraph. i want to know what is the reason behind that. I have also tried to increase the width of the card, still no use

Just increase the .card width 186.73px to 300px to show the text set center.
https://prnt.sc/sI5QlsfkFTDE

Everything is fine.  You need to add text-align: center; for .card.  It will align everything inside it in centre.
However, applying same class to p will also result in same.  The content of the p will be centrally aligned.


.spotifyplaylists {
  padding: 20px 29px;
  h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}

.card {
  width: 186.73px;
  height: 237.14px;
  padding-top: 36px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 12px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  img {
    width: 152px;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    border-radius: 8px;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: var(--grey);
    line-height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
<div class="spotifyplaylists">
  <h1>Spotify Playlists</h1>
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100" alt="image">
      <p>With Sachin-Jigar, Amit Trivedi, Mithoon</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--cardcont ends-->
</div>
<!--spotiplay ends-->




i dont want to change the text-align of the paragraph , the justify content and align item both are centered, but its affect is only getting applied to img but not the paragraph. i want to know what is the reason behind that. I have also tried to increase the width of the card, still no use

p in inside the card and it contains text.  So it will have text-left by-default.  Hence, you need to change it's text-align property to centre.  If you do not want to do that then you have make text-align: center; of it's parent ie: .card.
Have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/ansarinaeemakhtar/cye6t1u3/14/.

You need to use the text-align property to align text content
You can use like this


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
  .spotifyplaylists {
    padding: 20px 29px;
    h1 {
      font-size: 24px;
    }
  }
  
  .card {
    width: 186.73px;
    height: 237.14px;
    padding-top: 36px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 12px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    img {
      width: 152px;
      aspect-ratio: 1 1;
      border-radius: 8px;
    }
    p {
      font-size: 12px;
      color: var(--grey);
      line-height: 16px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="spotifyplaylists">
    <h1>Spotify Playlists</h1>
    <div class="card-container">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="./asset 19.jpeg" alt="image" />
        <p>With Sachin-Jigar, Amit Trivedi, Mithoon</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--cardcont ends-->
  </div>
  <!--spotiplay ends-->
</body>

</html>



